# How do I create write services in the Wagtail api?

Tags: wagtail

I want to be able to crud stuff via the api. Does anybody have any idea of how I would go about that?

Comment: As far as I know, the Wagtail API is read only. The write component is the /admin/ functionality. Although I'd be happy if I was wrong about this!

Comment: You're not wrong. I did create a patch to add write functionality but I've only tested it against the ModelAdmin stuff. No idea if it works with Pages, StreamField, etc.

Comment: I think the streamfields are going to be tricky. I don't know exactly how they're created, I've never dug into them that far. I assume it's a massive JSON (or Py Dict) stored as a string. But how that's parsed and updated is beyond my knowledge. Everything else should be as straight forward as Django Models though, since they're all derivatives of Django Models.